# On kernels of commuting operators in infinite dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional vector space, and let $\operatorname{S},\operatorname{T}\in\mbox{End}(X)$ be two operators such that:

1. $\operatorname{T}\operatorname{S}=\operatorname{S}\operatorname{T}$, i.e., the two operators commute
2. $\operatorname{T}X=X$, i.e., $\operatorname{T}$ is onto
3. $\ker\operatorname{S}\subset\operatorname{S}X$, i.e., the kernel of $\operatorname{S}$ is inside its image

**Question:** Is it true that $\ker\operatorname{T}\subset\operatorname{S}X$ ?

This should be rather elementary, but I am somehow stuck. Thank you.

**Update:** Ok, I seem to have a counterexample. Let $X=C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\oplus C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, pairs of smooth real functions $(f_1,f_2)$. Let $\operatorname{T}(f_1,f_2)=(f_1',f_2')$ (componentwise derivative) and let $\operatorname{S}(f_1,f_2)=(f_2,0)$. Then $\ker\operatorname{S}=\operatorname{S}X=C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\oplus0$ but $\ker\operatorname{T}=\mathbb{R}^2\oplus\mathbb{R}^2$ where $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is realized as the linear function $f(x)=ax+b$ on $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Could you please let me know what $End(X)$ is.

Comment: For a vector space $X$, by $\mbox{End}(X)$ I denote the ring of endomorphisms of $X$. This is just fancy notation meaning simply 'a linear operator on $X$'.

Comment: Thanks. It is not much easy to prove it!